# Add counter to consecutive observations of categorical variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with a variable that groups my observations (ID) and another variable that is categorical (type). I am working in R and am trying to make a new variable that counts consecutive observations of the same type within ID (the data are time series). See the example table below- Counter is the variable I want to create. It doesn't really matter whether 0 gets counted or not.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep("a", 7), rep("b", 4)),
                  type = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0),
                  counter = c(0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0))
```

So far I am able to make the counter, though probably not in the most efficient manner, but am struggling with doing this within the grouping (ID) and effectively switching between type = 1 and type = 2. The code I wrote to make the counter is below. Any ideas on how to do this efficiently? Thanks.

```
dat$counter <- 0
counter     <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  if(dat[i,"type"] != 0){
    counter <- counter + 1
    dat[i,"count"] <- counter
    # use to differentiate between 1 and 2?
    this_group <- dat[i,"type"]
  }
  if(dat[i,"type"] == 0){
    counter <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot one `)` in the for loop `for(i in 1:nrow(dat)` -- added –

Comment: And I don't understand your question. What di you have t start with (no `counter`?) and what `counter` do you want to create - the one in your first `dat` instruction,or the one your code below gives?

Comment: @vaettchen thanks. I need to create the `counter` variable in the `dat` supplied in my post. the `counter` create with my code is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each `id`, `type` and consecutive rows starting with `type` 0 create a sequence using `ave` and `seq_along`.  No packages are used:

```
transform(dat, 
  counter = (type > 0) * ave(type, id, type, cumsum(type == 0), FUN = seq_along))
```

giving:

```
   id type counter
1   a    0       0
2   a    1       1
3   a    1       2
4   a    2       1
5   a    2       2
6   a    0       0
7   a    1       1
8   b    1       1
9   b    1       2
10  b    2       1
11  b    0       0
```

Comment: Thanks - this solution worked perfectly. Very simple. Close to a million observations, so this was very fast. I tried a couple solutions with ave and could never figure it out- it helped seeing this. Marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(counter = case_when(
    type == 0 ~ 0,
    id != lag(id) ~ 1,
    type != lag(type) ~ 1
  )) %>%
  mutate(counter = case_when(
    id != lag(id) ~ 1,
    type == lag(type) ~ lag(counter) + 1,
    T ~ counter
  ))
```

Result:

```
   id type counter
1   a    0       0
2   a    1       1
3   a    1       2
4   a    2       1
5   a    2       2
6   a    0       0
7   a    1       1
8   b    1       1
9   b    1       2
10  b    2       1
11  b    0       0
```

Note: some of the code is repeated in both of the `case_when()` arguments, but those repeats are necessary to cover the many conditions.

I tested this code in various conditions and it seemed robust. One thing that it does not handle is if you have a repeat at the very last value (it will return `NA` because I use `lag()`).

This longer code also covers this situation and (I think) should work regardless of your code:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(counter = case_when(
    type == 0 ~ 0,
    type != lag(type) ~ 1
  )) %>%
  mutate(counter = case_when(
    id != lag(id) ~ 1,
    type == lag(type) ~ lag(counter) + 1,
    T ~ counter
  )) %>%
  mutate(counter = case_when(
    is.na(counter) ~ lag(counter) + 1,
    T ~ counter
  ))
```

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted the post. This was really helpful, but I accepted the other answer due to its simplicity, no Na, and its robustness.